# when is interchanging order of integration preserve the result?

Tags: calculus

When is $\int_a^b \int_c^d f(x,y)dxdy= \int_c^d \int_a^b f(x,y)dxdy$?

is $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full answer is not trivial but, fortunately, there is the Fubini-Tonelli theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Regarding your question, in the special case in which $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$, then IF
$$
A=\int dx \int dy f(x,y)
$$
exists, you can conclude that also 
$$
B=\int dy \int dx f(x,y)
$$
exists and that $A=B$.

Proof: the integration variables are dummy variables, so call $x$ as $y$ and $y$ as $x$, then use the property $f(*,**)=f(**,*)$.